# Escaping string arugments to subprocess calls in Windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, subprocess, clipboard

Why does `Example one` copy `hello world` to my clip board but not `Example two`?

```
# Example one
subprocess.check_output(["echo", "hello world", "|", "clip"], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

# Example two
subprocess.check_output(["echo", "hello \n world", "|", "clip"], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Another issues is that `Example one` copies hello world with quotes around it like so:

```
"hello world"
```

So, how do I copy text with multiple lines into the clipboard without double-quotes?

Comment: I don't know why you'd want to use the cmd shell for this; that's a headache. You can simply use `p = Popen('clip.exe', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True);` `p.communicate('hello\nworld');` `p.wait()`.

Comment: @eryksun why didn't you answer this?! I've got no love for cmd shell. I must need it to work.

Comment: I wasn't really answering the question as much as avoiding it. Whenever I think I have a handle on how cmd.exe will parse a command line, I get burned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @eryksun, this solves the issue:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('clip.exe', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
p.communicate('hello \n world')
p.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because you're using `shell=True`, refactor your code to not use it.

But I would suggest abandoning this approach alltogether and use [pyperclip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyperclip/) for the clipboard support. It's cross-platform and freely available.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work at all. `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`